# Check if form date is today and if server time is after 3:00pm EST

Tags: php, validation, date, time

I would like to perform the following in PHP (I am using version 5.2):

```
IF form_date = current_date AND server_time >= 3:00pm EST
GIVE ERROR
```

form_date: the date the user enters into the form.

current_date: today's date.

server_time: the current time as supplied by the host server.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//time validation
if (date("Gi") > '1500') {
    $process_result['custom_error'] = "You not able to register after 3 PM";
}
```

I am not sure how to finish this off as PHP is not my thing, at all.  Also, will the server only return whatever timezone it is set in, or can this be changed to a specific timezone such as Eastern Standard (EST)?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

To set the default time zone use: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

To finish the code I would redirect to another page which tells the user it has failed so altogether:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
if (date("Gi") > '1500') {
    header("Location: http://example.com/failed_registration.php");
}else{
 //how are you going to register them?
}
```

Comment: This code is actually a validation check that exists within a much larger PHP file.  That said, while this sets the timezone and checks the time... how can I also ensure that this time check only occurs if the user selected a date that is the same as today's date?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following which works great.

```
//time validation for day-of reservations
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
if (date("Gi") >= '1500'){
    if (date("m.d.y") == date("m.d.y",strtotime($table_data['element_' . $date_element_id]))){
    $error_elements[$date_element_id] = 'You are not able to make an online reservation for today, after 3:00pm EST.  Please call us at xxx-xxx-xxxx to make your reservation.';
    }
}
```